# Is it possible to pipe code to R or Rscript in commandline?

Tags: r, command-line

for example, test.R is a one line file:

```
$ cat test.R  
# print('Hello, world!')
```

we can run this file by `Rscript test.R` or `R CMD BATCH test.R`. However, is it possible to instruct R to execute code piped to it, something like `cat test.R | Rscript` or `cat test.R | R CMD BATCH` (both doesn't work)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rscript will not listen to stdin:

```
$ echo "2 + 2" | Rscript

Usage: /path/to/Rscript [--options] [-e expr [-e expr2 ...] | file] [args]

--options accepted are
  --help              Print usage and exit
  --version           Print version and exit
  --verbose           Print information on progress
  --default-packages=list
                      Where 'list' is a comma-separated set
                        of package names, or 'NULL'
or options to R, in addition to --slave --no-restore, such as
  --save              Do save workspace at the end of the session
  --no-environ        Don't read the site and user environment files
  --no-site-file      Don't read the site-wide Rprofile
  --no-init-file      Don't read the user R profile
  --restore           Do restore previously saved objects at startup
  --vanilla           Combine --no-save, --no-restore, --no-site-file
                        --no-init-file and --no-environ

'file' may contain spaces but not shell metacharacters
Expressions (one or more '-e <expr>') may be used *instead* of 'file'
See also  ?Rscript  from within R
$
```

But littler has been doing this just fine as it was built for this (and more):

```
$ echo "2 + 2" | r -p                # -p switch needed for print
[1] 4
$ echo "print(2 + 2)" | r 
[1] 4
$
```

Note that operations are by default "silent" either explicit `print()` statements or the `-p` flag are your friend.

For completeness, R can now do it too but I forget when it was added:

```
$ echo "2 + 2" | R --slave
[1] 4
$
```

I have an [older blog post comparing the start-up speeds](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2014/09/02/), so my money is still on littler for these things -- and I have numerous scripts and cron jobs using it as it "just works".

Comment: I installed your `littler` package inside R, and added `r` to my `~/.bashrc` with `alias`. It worked nicely!

Comment: Out of curiousity, by the alias?   To get the binary from the installed package?   I usually just softlink to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: the package is installed to `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/littler/bin/r` by default. In case we don't have write access in `/usr/local/bin`, I think it is easier to change `.bashrc`.

Comment: Quite right. If you can't sudo then that is all you get, sadly.